# java.net.MalformedURLException in android while accessing asp.net Web API

Tags: java, android, rest, asp.net-web-api, malformedurlexception

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093864/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol-on-url-based-on-a-string-modified-wi), it's not my case, since I don't have backslashes in my url,
I have simple URL like, `https://url.com/login`

My **Code**,

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    URL url = new URL("https://url.net/login/");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        FloatingActionButton btn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);
        EditText edtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernm);
        EditText edtxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usrpwd);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            readStream(in);
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

**Screen shot**:

When I hover on `new URL();`, I get **error** as:

> Unhandled Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException

That's why I'm getting another error at line,

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
readStream(in);
```

in stack Trace I'm getting **error** as,

```
Error:(48, 13) error: cannot find symbol method readStream(InputStream)
```

Comment: Please post source code as text, not as images.

Comment: image is for error, That's the line of error and I'm getting error as `Error:(48, 13) error: cannot find symbol method readStream(InputStream)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I hover on new URL();, I get error as:

The `URL()` constructor throws `java.net.MalformedURLException`. You need to wrap that constructor call in a `try`/`catch` block.

> That's why I'm getting another error at line,

That is because `getInputStream()` also throws checked exceptions. You need to wrap that code in a `try`/`catch` block.

> That's the line of error and I'm getting error as Error:(48, 13) error: cannot find symbol method readStream(InputStream)

That is because you did not implement a method named `readStream()` on this class.

All of this is covered in any decent book or course on Java programming.

Eventually, once you get past these compile errors, your code will crash at runtime with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, as you cannot perform network I/O on the main application thread. You will need to move this HTTP code to a background thread, either one that you create yourself or by using an HTTP client API that can handle it for you (e.g., OkHttp).