# java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: location

Tags: java, android, url, jsoup

I am working on a project with jsoup. The point is that I am not able to connect to the target URL. I get this error:

```js
W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: location
```

I don't know exactly what `unknown protocol: location` means.

This is my code. The code works perfectly with other websites, but there is one website where it doesn't work.

```js
    public class connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String string;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements elements = document.select("div.tray_name");
                string = elements.html();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            textView.setText(string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Code added to the post.

Comment: We need the url too.

Comment: You haven't included a stack trace, so it's difficult to analyse this, however this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093864 suggests that this sort of thing will occur if you haven't URL encoded the URL string.

Answer (score 1):

You can only create a `java.net.URL` with a known protocol.

It appears the you are attempting to create a `URL` of the form:

```
location:some_format_dependent_on_the_meaning_of_location
```

Here's a self contained example to show `MalformedURLException` being thrown:

```
interface Code {
    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var url = new java.net.URL("location://1.1.1.1");

    }
}
```

Which displays:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: location
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:674)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:563)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:510)
    at Code.main(Code.java:3)
```

You can replace the list of known protocols using the process wide `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory` or for an individiual URL using the `URL(URL context, String spec, URLStreamHandler handler)` constructor. (Both require security permissions if you are running under a reasonable `SecurityManager`.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is just a regular URL format: h ttps://www.my-site.com/ So I still don't know what location means.

Comment: @DevEloper Somewhere (pointed to by the stack trace) you will have sent a `String` starting with `location:` to the constructor of a `java.net.URL`. That's what the exception message means.