# I am facing java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: While converting url to bitmap in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-bitmap, worker

I am trying to convert url to bitmap and then set that bitmap to background as wallpaper. And all this process is getting done in background with the use of worker class in android. But I am getting no protocol error. I am fetching any one random wallpaper link from firebase then I am trying to convert it into bitmap by

```
  try {
                        URL url = new URL(image_url);
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(image,null,false,WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);

                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("tag102",e.getMessage());
                    }
```

But this method gave me this error in logcat

```
2022-07-08 03:15:07.544 25513-25752/com.nightowl.stylo E/tag102: no protocol:
```

But when I put hardcoded string (showed in below method) in url method parameter then it return bitmap without any error. and wallpaper also gets changed

```
 try {
                        URL url = new URL("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6336035/pexels-photo-6336035.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800");
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(image,null,false,WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);

                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("tag102",e.getMessage());
                    }
```

But i want random string to set and get me bitmap from that. So how i can achieve that? I also try to encode url by

```
 try {
        encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(image_url, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("tag3",e.toString());
    }
```

I am using three kind of url in this project

1. https://images.pexels.com/photos/6336035/pexels-photo-6336035.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800
2. https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/27/22/07/naruto-5783102_960_720.png
3. https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641414315243-196e7382c32d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1178&q=80

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Might be helpful ENCODE url params  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093864/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol-on-url-based-on-a-string-modified-wi

Comment: Thanks buddy my problem is solved without encoding the url.